# how to set domain with python in odoo

Tags: odoo, python-3.8, enterprise, erp, odoo-14

Is it possible to set domain on the python side without putting it in view?
I tried to set the domain in the customer field (sale order) based on branch in the Customer menu/template

I have tried this but why it doesn't work ?

```
@api.onchange('partner_id')
def _onchange_cust_domain(self):
    for rec in self:
        if self.branch_id.id:
            cust_list = rec.partner_id.branch_id.id
        return {'domain' : {'partner_id' : [('branch_id', '=', cust_list)]}}
```

Comment: Why can't you put the domain in the view?

Comment: I can put the domain in the view, but if can set the domain only in python it would be better, because no need to upgrade the module. and I also tried it in view, but the customer doesn't even appear, maybe there was something wrong in adding the domain @CZoellner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set the `partner_id` domain when the `branch_id` field value changes, use the following `onchange` function:

***Example:***

```py
@api.onchange('branch_id')
def onchange_branch_id(self):
    if self.branch_id:
        return {'domain': {'partner_id': ['|', ('branch_id', '=', False), ('branch_id', '=', self.branch_id.id)]}}
```

Odoo sets by default the following [domain](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/addons/sale/models/sale.py#L193) from the python code:

```
['|', ('company_id', '=', False), ('company_id', '=', company_id)]
```

Comment: thanks for answering, I've tried your suggestion but it doesn't change anything. I want make only customers that are shown correspond to the selected branch, but some customers have empty branches, and some have branches. if it's empty it means it can be used in all branches

Comment: Sorry i made typo, it works by adding domain like this : {'domain': {'partner_id': [('branch_id', '=', self.branch_id.id)]}}  , but the customers who have empty branches cannot be selected or appears @Kenly

Comment: You can use the | operator to include customers without branches: `'|', ('branch_id', '=', False),`. Check my edit

Comment: I've tried it and it works, but the name that appears after selecting a branch becomes random again, what if want to display the customer's name after the branch that was selected first? so what is displayed is the customer's name according to the selected branch but at the same time you can also search for customers with empty branches

Comment: Do you want to include the branch name in the partner displayed name?

Comment: Yes, maybe you have reference or documentation about that @Kenly

Comment: You can override the `name_get` function to append the branch name to the partner name as they did for the [tax name to include its type](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/addons/account/models/account_tax.py#L195-L206)

Answer (score 2):

Returning a domain using `onchange method` has been [deprecated](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/odoo/models.py#L6008) in Odoo 14.

You can use the new way used by Odoo:
Returning a domain using onchange method has been deprecated in Odoo 14.

You can use [this new way](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/pull/41918#issuecomment-824946980).

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you are making a domain for a field partner_id, but in the onchange method of the same field.
It makes no sense to me. So if you put a Customer with branch X, then you can only search customers of branch X for that sale_order (if that domain do the job).
I dont know what are you trying to do exactly, but i think than changing a domain in the same field you are changing the value it is no possible.

Your code would be correct if that domain applies to another field.

This is a working exaple. Notice that onchange field method and field to apply domain are diferent:

```py
    @api.onchange('operating_unit_id')
    def _applicants_onchange(self):
        if self.operating_unit_id:
            return {'domain': {'applicant_id': [('default_operating_unit_id', '=', self.operating_unit_id.id)]}}
        return {}
```